# "Follow religiously" in a non religious context

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, popular-refrains

What is another word for "follow religiously" in a non religious context?

> - Support will agree with their candidate's views religiously despite being obviously flawed, as he is their candidate
> - Interns suck up to the decision maker religiously to gain favour and get access to their network

Detailed Background:

In a large company, coworkers automatically support the viewpoints of this high position individual, disagree with his stance, and he will scorn you, you won't get support from coworkers and will be a adverse on your career growth in the company as he is notorious for unfairly badmouth you behind your back for disagreeing with him as he has a tremendous belief of self worth. Strongly agreeing with him will be good for your career as he is trusted in the company and he is a key decision maker. The end result irrespective of the viewpoints made, his positions are blindly followed although some are clearly incorrect, but people don't call him out for it. People will agree him to try gain favour as they keep the end result in mind.

I find in describing the above situation I use too many words and would like to use less. IMO using too many words does make it sound complainy.

Edit:
I am also looking for a noun to describe the person (still same context) e.g. follow blindly without examination of their teaching.

> Tom is a *nincompoop* for continuing to follow Peter and think he is an intellectual genius

Comment: Definition says with care and dedication. I'm looking for more like blindly followed or followed for the sake of following to be part of the "in-group"

Comment: Sycophant or Servile come to mind.

Comment: [Dedication](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dedication) is certainly worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*lackey*

> a person who is or acts like a weak servant of someone powerful

[Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lackey)

Answer (score 1):

You should check ***zealously***.

> Support will agree with their candidate's views ***zealously*** despite
>   being obviously flawed, as he is their candidate.
>   Interns suck up to
>   the decision maker ***zealously*** to gain favour and get access to their
>   network.

Someone who is *zealous* is just driven by their *zeal* towards their ultimate aim (in the context) like making the candidate win or gain favour of the target person, so they may end up blindly supporting them.

M-W:

> **[zealous](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/zealous)**
>   *adjective*
>
> :  marked by fervent **partisanship** for a person, a cause, or an ideal :
>   filled with or characterized by **zeal** : *zealous missionaries*
>
> - **zealously** *adverb*
>
> **[zeal](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/zeal)**
>   *noun*
>
> :  eagerness and ardent interest in pursuit of something :  fervor :
>   *her zeal to succeed strained her relationships*
>
> **[partisan](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/partisan[1])**
>   *noun*
>
> **1** :  a firm adherent to a party, faction, cause, or person; especially :  one *exhibiting **blind**, **prejudiced**, and
>   **unreasoning allegiance***
>
> - partisan *adjective*
> - partisanly *adverb*
> - **partisanship** *noun*

Comment: Thanks. Good suggestions. Zealot and zealously still has a strong religious connection. Partisan doesn't necessary mean he is a subordinate. I thought of word like concubine, concubinage might also be suitable if it didn't have such a strong sexual meaning

Comment: I haven't mentioned _zealot_, and _zealous_ does not connote anything religious IMHO. _Partisan_ was mentioned not as a suggestion on its own but only to clarify the definition of _zealous_.

Comment: Yep, Zealot and the words derived from it have a religious origin, and still have pro- and anti-Zealot factions.

Answer (score 0):

A political word that could fit that is similar to partisan but with more focus on being a blind follower.

*apparatchik*

> 1:  a member of a Communist apparat
>
> 2:  a blindly devoted official, follower, or member of an organization (as a corporation or political party)

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apparatchik)